# C++ library for merging images

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, merge, cimg

I need to merge a couple of images so that image2 covers parts of image1 and so on. I found the [CImg library](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/annotated.html) but I couldn't find out how to use it for my purposes.

Is there any other library I could use or may I achieve this with CImg?

Comment: check out Magick++ 
http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/

Comment: Look at [OpenCV Library](http://docs.opencv.org/index.html). If you read the reference documentation, you will find examples on how to copy a smaller image to a sub rectangle of a bigger image.

Comment: I already know OpenCV, but I think it has too much overhead for my rather simple purpose. On the contrary, Magick++ seems to be exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I created two images like this with ImageMagick:

```
convert -size 400x300 gradient:blue-yellow PNG24:gradient.png
```

[image]

```
convert -size 100x100 xc:fuchsia overlay.png
```

[image]

And then ran this `CImg` code:

```
#define cimg_use_png
#define cimg_display 0
#include "CImg.h"
using namespace cimg_library;
int main() {
   CImg<unsigned char> gradient("gradient.png");
   CImg<unsigned char> overlay("overlay.png");
   gradient.draw_image(150,50,overlay);
   gradient.save_png("result.png");
}
```

And got this:

[image]